# Python/QT - What can I do to get 4 pixel borders between series of widgets?

Tags: python, qt, border, pyside

I've looked at the PySide and QT docs, and googled but not finding a solution yet.

In this Python 2.7/Qt4.8 (PySide) example, I have a series of widgets that have 4 px rounded borders via CSS. What I'm attempting to do is place these widgets next to each other and have the borders in between the widgets the same thickenss as the rest. In my case, technically, QT is doing exactly what I'm asking it, but I need something special so that I end up with 4 px borders between each widget, not 8 (4 x 2).

Here is what I'm getting.

[image]

Here is what I need (Photoshopped)

[image]

Here is the sample code.

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

css = '''
QLabel{
    border: 4px solid #555555;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
'''

class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(css)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        for i in range(3):
            label = QLabel('hello')
            layout.addWidget(label)

app = QApplication([])
win = MainWidget()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried simply not rendering the bottom borders for the top 2 widgets, and that gets me part of the way there, but the solution is semi hideous, and won't work.

What can I do to get 4 px borders between these widgets?

Comment: What about a spacing in the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to adjust the margins :

```
css = '''

QLabel{
    border: 4px solid #555555;
    margin-top: -1;
    margin-bottom: -1;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
'''
```

(I tried with -2 first, but the offset causes a bad effect)

**EDIT :**

The following way allows to control the margins with more accuracy, without ugly cropping :

```
css = '''
QLabel{
    border: 4px solid #555555;
    border-radius: 6px;

}
*[nobottom="true"]{
    margin-bottom: -2;    

}
*[notopnobottom="true"]{
    margin-top: -2;
    margin-bottom: -2;    

}
*[notop="true"]{
    margin-top: -2;
}
'''

class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(css)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        labeltop = QLabel('hello')
        labeltop.setProperty('nobottom', True)
        labelmid = QLabel('hello')
        labelmid.setProperty('notopnobottom', True)
        labelbottom = QLabel('hello')
        labelbottom.setProperty('notop', True)
        layout.addWidget(labeltop)
        layout.addWidget(labelmid)
        layout.addWidget(labelbottom)
```

Comment: Almost! The rounded portions are getting slightly chopped from the crop effect of the CSS margin property, which I think you noticed when setting said properties to -2.

Comment: @PaulW, how did you select the 2 top widgets in your tests, is there a css selector or did you name the widgets ? a question for an answer :p

Comment: @PRMourea, in Python, I would setProperty('nonbottom', True) for the top 2 widgets, and then in CSS select said widgets by *[nonbottom="true"]{bla bla bla;}.